# AWS Code Build with Github - get changed files

Tags: aws-codebuild

Tangentially related to: [AWS CodeBuild with GitHub - only for specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410673/aws-codebuild-with-github-only-for-specific-directory)

I have a codebuild project and a github repo with many files in it. A user may update any of these files in the git repo. I want to pass the name of the altered file(s) into my buildspec.yaml somehow; IE my merge job logic, specified in the buildspec.yaml, needs to know what files changed to do a per-file operation.

I am *not* talking about filters; Ie "only trigger this if X,Y,Z changed". Becuase the filter is there for a large number of XYZ, but I need to know *which* file(s) changed in my buildspec. IE something like $CHANGED_FILE_LIST.

I don't see this here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html

Maybe we have to do something like this: [how to find out list of all changed files in git for full jenkins build and not for a particular commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979573/how-to-find-out-list-of-all-changed-files-in-git-for-full-jenkins-build-and-not/40555250)

`git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT`

but one would think this meta info could be provided by codebuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git diff --name-status $CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_BASE_REF` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a blessed CodeBuild way to do this, but assuming you have access to a GitHub token in the build, you can query the GitHub metadata endpoint to get the info you need. Something like

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ${yourtoken}" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/commits/${CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION} | jq '.files[].filename'
```

will return a list of files in the commit.

See https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits#get-a-commit for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git diff --name-only $$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION $$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT`

Where **$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT** is the commit id of the previous commit. And **$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION** is the commit id of the actual one.

Inside a build phase you can check the change with:

-

```
 |
    if [ "$(git diff --name-only $CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | grep -e <filde_path>)" != "" ]; then
      #your code;
    fi
```